# Lenovo X220 Digitizer Pen Not Working

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, wacom

Recently purchased a refurbished Lenovo X220 Thinkpad and the digitizer is not working at all (Windows or Ubuntu). Since both OS's are not detecting it I'm starting to suspect its a hardware rather than driver issue but I'm hoping with Ubuntu we can nail down if there's something physically wrong with the digitizer. This is a bit similar to this question
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1833248.html
Can anyone help me out or list some terminal commands I should start with to pinpoint possible problems?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a BIOS option to enable/disable it?

Do you know (e.g. from the specs) if the digitizer is connected via PCI or USB? In the first case you can use `lspci` to see if it shows up, in the second case, try `lsusb`. Both tools support the `-v` option for more verbose output. Yet another tool to list the hardware that is detected in your system is `lshw`.

Does it show up in the file `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, as mentioned in the forum thread you refer to?